# Can we form a sequence from a given set?

Tags: set-theory

Let's say we have a set $A$ of natural numbers such as
$$
A = \{ 9, 6, 5, 2 \}.
$$
I want to form a sequence $B$ that have all elements of $A$ such as
$$
B = (2, 5, 6, 9).
$$
The order doesn't matter, but I need to form a unique sequence of the elements of $A$.

I know sequence $B$ is a function from $4$ to $A$, so I guess I need a formula to separate $B$ from the Cartesian
product $4\times B$. But I can't think of a formula to do this.

Then, I realize that what I want is a way to pick one function from the set of all function from $4$ to $A$, that is $A^4$. But I can't think of a way to do this either. Maybe I can do something with the axiom of choice, but this is a part of an exercise that I am not allow to use the axiom of choice.

Comment: If $A$ is a subset of the natural numbers, then just order them from smallest to largest.

Comment: This post might help you https://mathoverflow.net/a/32545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A be a set of natural numbers, with cardinality |A| = m

Let $B_{0} $ = least element in A

and $B_{n+1}$ = least element in A greater than $B_{n}$

then the sequence: <$B_{n}$ | n < m > where n is a natural number. Is your desired sequence.

If you want a formula for finding the least element in a set of Natural Numbers,

We define a recursive function with domain |A|

f(0) = ∩A

f(n+1) = ∩(A \ {f(a)| a<n+1})

where A \ B := {x|x∈A and x∉B}

then your sequence is:

<f(n)| n < |A|>

Ex. Let A = {2,1,4}

f(0) = ∩A = 1

f(1) = ∩(A \ {f(0)})= 2

f(2) = ∩(A \ {f(0),f(1)}) = 4

<f(0),f(1),f(2)> = <1,2,4>

Note: Here, we are using the Von Neumann definition of Ordinals to represent natural numbers, this construction works because if X is a set of Ordinals, ∩X is the inf(X)

Comment: Awesome power of the axiom of replacement, I suppose. I always fail when I try to do computational thing in the language of set theory. This is enlightening. Thanks you very much.